# Consume soap Service in Apache Camel

Tags: apache, apache-camel

i want to consume soap web serivce in apache camel using Java DSL.Any way without CXF.i have already try using CXF with spring.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that used only camel http without cxf. If you need to perform some modifications of SOAP request string you can just change "constant" to something like "spel".

```
<setBody><constant><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <MyAction>
     <myparam>ABC</myparam>
  </MyAction>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>]]></constant></setBody>
<setHeader headerName="SOAPAction"><constant>MySOAPAction</constant></setHeader>
<setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod"><constant>POST</constant></setHeader>
<setHeader headerName="Content-Type"><constant>text/xml;charset=UTF-8</constant></setHeader>
<to uri="http://myserver:1234" />
```

Same with Java DSL

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
  public void configure() {
    from("direct:start")
      .setBody(constant("")) // String SOAP content from XML example
      .setHeader("SOAPAction", constant("MySOAPAction"))
      .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", constant("POST"))
      .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("text/xml;charset=UTF-8"))
      .to("http://myserver:1234")
      .log("SOAP service called"); // Here you can process service response
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share me a simple example for consume soap Service using camel http without cxf and spring.

Comment: Added Java DSL example